# php remove from array if property value is in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove all elements from arr2 that have a type contained in arr1:

```
    arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    arr2 = [
        [
        'name' => 'jane',
        'type' => 'X'
        ],
        [
        'name' => 'jon',
        'type' => 'B'
        ]
    ]
```

So jon should be removed. Is there some built in function like array_diff?

Comment: No, use `foreach+unset` or `array_filter` with a callback.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of solutions using `array_filter`:

```
print_r(array_filter(
    $arr2, 
    function($v) use($arr1) { return !in_array($v['type'], $arr1); }
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another if the `type` is unique:

```
$result = array_diff_key(array_column($arr2, null, 'type'), array_flip($arr1));
```

- extract an array from `$arr2` keyed (indexed) by the `type` column
- flip `$arr1` to get values as keys
- get the key differences

Run `array_values` on it to re-index if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do it with just one built-in array function, but you can combine some of them to do it.

```
$record_types = array_column($arr2, 'type');

$records_to_keep = array_diff($record_types, $arr1);

$result = array_intersect_key($arr2, $records_to_keep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach the 2nd array and check if the type is in arr1. If so then simply delete(unset) it.

```
foreach(array_keys(arr2) as $Key) {
   if (in_array(arr2[$Key]['type'],arr1)) { unset(arr2[$Key]); }
}
```